# Map modification not triggering store update

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am adding NGRX to my application in angular 4.

I have an issue with store updating over a Map Object.

My store is a `Map<string,MyObj>;`

When I update the map, the store is updated, but the observable for changes do not fire on my store.

```
const ACTION_Increment = (state: Map<string,MyObj> = initialState, action:Increment) => {
    if(!state.get(action.payload.id)) state.set(action.payload.id, action.payload.myobj);
    else state.set(action.payload.id, {...state.get(action.payload.id), ...action.payload.myobj});


    console.log("Status Updated : ", state)
    return state;
}

const ACTION_Decrement = (state: Map<string,MyObj> = initialState, action:Increment) => {
    console.log("Status Updated : ", state)
    return new Map<string,MyObj>();
}
```

Here an exemple on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-seed-oq9ldt).

If you click + I add a random element to my store, but no trigger are fired, if I press - I reset the map so assign a new object, and in this case, the trigger is fired.

How can I make it trigger in booth situation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed doing :

```
return new Map(state);
```